母親の呼び方 (連絡先として)
母親を呼ぶとは「お母さん」や「母ちゃん」等、人と話す時には自分の母親のことを「はは」で、相手の母親を「お母さん」で呼びますよね。で、日本の人は一般的に自分の母親を連絡先リストにどう入力しますか。「お母さん」などか「はは」か

特にルールはありません。本名の人も多いですし、「ママ」「お母さん」などの人もいます。「母上」「母君」など普段使わない敬称を敢えて使う人もいます。

皆さんは親の携帯の登録名はどうしてますか？
携帯電話のアドレス帳に両親の名前はなんて登録してありますか？
アドレス帳の親の名前は普通 本名ですか？
携帯電話に家族をどういう名前で登録してますか？

